Conditional trace routing in OpenTelemetry Collector
I am currently using OpenTelemetry collectors to gather traces through gRPC from our application before sending them to Grafana Tempo.
However, I now have the need of performing routing on those traces. For instance:
Trace with attribute1=AAAA needs to be routed to Exporter A and default exporter
Trace with attribute1=BBBB needs to be routed to Exporter B and default exporter
The amount of possible values for attribute1 would be a static list at a given point in time (the list can be changed manually overtime) but possibly contain dozens of possible values.
I have experimented with the filter processor available in the OpenTelemetry collector but from my tests, it seems that if I want to have 3 possible receivers, each trace would have to go through 3 different filter processors, potentially increasing the resource usage of the collector by X%, hence it doesn't seem to be a scalable option.
Is there any recommended way to implement such features?
Thanks in advance for your help
